# mysql : issue with NOT IN query syntax

Tags: mysql

why does this query doesn't return any result  (it should return results)

```
SELECT id FROM T_CLIENT where id 
    not in (select distinct client_id from T_VENTE);
```

whereas this one does.

```
SELECT *
FROM T_CLIENT LEFT JOIN T_VENTE ON T_VENTE.client_id=T_CLIENT.id
WHERE T_VENTE.client_id IS NULL;
```

Those two queries seems the same to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The NOT IN query returns null. Instead use NOT EXISTS:

```
SELECT id FROM T_CLIENT c where NOT EXISTS  
    (select 1 from T_VENTE v where v.client_id = c.id);
```

Comment: this query returns no result